# Change content in an div through button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Maybe this is duplicate, i don't know

But how do i so my text input changes into text ?

```
<input type='text' id='input_id' /> 
<button id='saveName'>Save name</button> 
<div id='box_id'></div> 

<script> 
    document.getElementById('saveName').addEventListener('click', function() { 
        var name = document.getElementById('input_id').value; 
        document.getElementById('box_id').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + name; 
    }, false); 
</script>
```

So when the button is pressed the `input`-tag and the 
`button`-tag changes

to the Username: text input

Almost like a login but without servers and emails etc.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the problem you are facing? and what you want to do?

Comment: which part of your code is not working? http://jsfiddle.net/YTZ4v/ note: the js in the fiddle loads onload

Comment: It all works i know... but i want to when the button is clicked the button and input disappears and the box_id comes in with the username

Comment: @Liam_Rab33 Satisfied, then accept the answer.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want both the input and button to disappear you could add this to your JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('saveName').remove();
document.getElementById('input_id').remove();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YTZ4v/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code:

```
<input type='text' id='input_id' /> 
<button id='saveName' onClick="callMethod()">Save name</button> 
<div id='box_id'></div> 

<script> 
function callMethod(){
var name = document.getElementById('input_id').value; 
document.getElementById('box_id').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + name; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: But the input and button doesn't disappear ?

Comment: take a look on my next Answer.

Answer (score 1):

It will work sure.

```
<script> 
 function callMethod(){

 document.getElementById('saveName').remove();
 document.getElementById('input_id').remove();
 document.getElementById('box_id').innerHTML = 'Welcome '+  document.getElementById('input_id').value;
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/UFRY6/)

## HTML

```
<div id="login">
    <input type='text' id='input_id' /> 
    <button id='saveName'>Save name</button>
</div>
<div id='box_id'>a</div>
```

## CSS

```
#box_id  {display:none; background:#ccc;}
#login, #box_id  {padding:20px; background:#eee;}
```

## JS

```
document.getElementById('saveName').addEventListener('click', function() { 
var name = document.getElementById('input_id').value; 
$('#login').hide();
document.getElementById('box_id').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + name; 
$('#box_id').css({'display': 'block' }); 
}, false);
```

Comment: Please take a look at my answer too, if it is useful, accept it, or increase it.

Answer (score 0):

It Will not required you to click or make button dissapear.

```
<input type='text' id='input_id' onblur="callMethod()" /> 

<div id='box_id'></div> 


<script> 
 function callMethod(){
 var name = document.getElementById('input_id').value; 
 document.getElementById('box_id').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + name; 
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do. But if you want to change `input` tag and `button` tag into form: Username: `text` remove these elements:

```
<input type='text' id='input_id' /> 
<button id='saveName'>Save name</button> 
<div id='box_id'></div> 
<script> 
document.getElementById('saveName').addEventListener('click', function() { 
var name = document.getElementById('input_id').value; 
document.getElementById('input_id').remove();
document.getElementById('saveName').remove();
document.getElementById('box_id').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + name; 
}, false); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Problem Solved, Accept if working.

```
<script> 
function callMethod(){
var name = document.getElementById('input_id').value; 
document.getElementById('box_id').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + name; 
document.getElementById('saveName').style.display="none";
document.getElementById('input_id').style.display="none";

}
</script>
```